# Spring Webflux: FilePart transferTo adds invisible character at the first line

Tags: java, spring-webflux

I'm using Spring Boot + webflux application and trying to implement Rest API endpoint for files uploading. Everything works fine but `org.springframework.http.codec.multipart.FilePart#transferTo` method adds some invisible character at first line first position.
In the screenshot below you can find that `original.toml` file has first line in blue and `uploaded.toml` has gray (Atom Editor doesn't recognize `[config]` as a valid toml key entry).

[image: screen]

Also `diff` gives me:

```
1c1
< [config]
---
> [config]
```

My code is:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.codec.multipart.FilePart;
import org.springframework.http.codec.multipart.Part;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@RestController
@Slf4j
public class UploadController {

  @PostMapping(value = "/upload",
      consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE,
      produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
  public Flux<String> uploadFiles(@RequestBody Flux<Part> parts) {
    return
        parts
            .filter(p -> p instanceof FilePart)
            .cast(FilePart.class)
            .flatMap(this::saveFile)
            .map(File::getName)
            .doFinally(s -> log.debug("Upload files process completed with signal: {}", s));
  }

  private Mono<File> saveFile(FilePart filePart) {
    Path target = Paths.get("").resolve(filePart.filename());
    try {
      Files.deleteIfExists(target);
      File file = Files.createFile(target).toFile();

      return filePart.transferTo(file)
          .map(r -> file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }

}
```

The issue is in `filePart.transferTo(file)` method. If I comment this line and just write custom string to the file then all is well, no any new symbols appear.

May be does it happen because of encoding? But i didn't find how can I specify charset for file transfer.

Please help me to solve this problem.